# Click function for each dynamically loaded buttons

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically loaded fields with buttons like

```
<input class="upload_image_23" type="text" size="36" name="products_image_large_new_23" value="" />
<input class="upload_image_button_24" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
<input class="upload_image_23" type="text" size="36" name="products_image_large_new_23" value="" />
<input class="upload_image_button_24" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
```

Now I wanted to modify this jquery function for all `upload_image_button_[any-number]` and `products_image_large_new_[any-number]`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.upload_image_button_[any-number]').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('.upload_image_[any-number]').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('.upload_image_[any-number]').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}

});
```

What should I include for `[any-number]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all elements with `id`s that start with `#upload_image_`, use this selector:

```
input[id^="upload_image_"]
```

And your code would become:

```
jQuery('input[class^="upload_image_button_"]').click(function() {
  var id = jQuery(this).attr('class').split('_').slice(-1);
  formfield = jQuery('.upload_image_' + id).attr('name');

  tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
  return false;
});
```

Read more about attribute selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

If your elements are in that *exact* order, you can also use this to get `formfield`:

```
  formfield = jQuery(this).prev().attr('name');
```

Comment: I think what is better is to add a classname to the buttons and use that as the selector. The existing classnames are actually IDs and should be changed to IDs: <input class="upload_image_button" id="upload_image_button_24" />

Comment: @Ringo: OP edited the question while I was writing my answer, but yes, that'd be a much better approach than unique class names.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(document.body).click(function () {
      $("div").each(function (i) {
       formfield = jQuery('#upload_image_[any-number]').attr('name');
      tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
     return false;

      });
    });
```

Comment: adding the click to the body seems like it would cause event propagation problems.